# Vim syntax highlighting problems in Polymer elements

Tags: javascript, html, vim, polymer

Google's Polymer elements generally include a markdown table of css variables in the first comment block. I've noticed that vim's syntax highlighting always craps out around here. I thought it was vim's fault, but I recently discovered that these comments are actually invalid HTML according to these [w3 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#comments) (it's illegal to include `--` anwhere inside an HTML5 comment).

What needs to change here? Should vim have a more lenient syntax highlighter, or should Polymer overhaul all of its jsdocs?

[image]

Edit: I've noticed the same syntax highlighting issues in Atom and Sublime as well (but not WebStorm).

Comment: Polymer is neither JavaScript nor HTML. If you want "proper" highlighting you'll either need to find a proper syntax script for Polymer or turn your components into valid HTML/JavaScript/CSS/whatever.

Comment: Give vim-polymer (https://github.com/bendavis78/vim-polymer) plugin a  try.

Comment: @romainl I'm not sure that's true, since Polymer components are `.html` files.

vim-polymer seems to just error out...it isn't very mature. Hm......any tips on how I might tweak html comment syntax myself?

Comment: `--` present in Polymer documentation actually comes from css3 specifications for `custom properties`. It's not possible to define these variables without them. You can check the specs [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/#defining-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this inside `:help html`:

```
    HTML comments are rather special (see an HTML reference document for the
    details), and the syntax coloring scheme will highlight all errors.
    However, if you prefer to use the wrong style (starts with ) you can define
        :let html_wrong_comments=1
```

This fixed the issue for me.